# Read whole directory and load into a view:Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to read all files from a directory and load whole directory as a view:

```
        public function load_root(){
             $this->load->helper('directory');
             $direct = APPPATH . "views/review";
             $mapd = directory_map($direct);
                foreach($mapd as $maps){
                $this->load->view('views/review'.$maps);
            }
```

I have tried this one but its just load first element that is on [0] index of the array into view and then generate an error

> "Unable to load the requested file: views/review/ajax.php"

please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function load_root(){
             $x=0;
             $this->load->helper('directory');
             $direct = APPPATH . "views/review/";
             $mapd = directory_map($direct);
             $ctr=count($mapd);
                foreach($mapd as $maps){
                  if($x<$ctr-1){
                    $this->load->view('review'.$mapd[$x]);//removed the views/
                    $x++;
                  }
                }
```

Comment: i have tried this code: and when i load this method its giving me this result:

Unable to load the requested file: reviewajax.php

Comment: Check if your $mapd is == reviewajax.php or your check your filename because filenames are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
public function load_root(){
    $this->load->helper('directory');
    $direct = APPPATH . "views/review";

    $data['mapd'] = directory_map($direct);

    $this->load->view('views/review'.$data);
}
```

**In View**

```
foreach ($mapd as $mapdItem) {
    echo ...
}
```